# How to convert pandas series containing time into datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one column consists of time in float format. So the time 7:03am is represented as `703.0` and 12am is `0.0`. There are some missing values as well so these are blank/na. I want to convert the entire series into a `datetime` series but I can't seem to do it.

So far, I tried

1. Converting to int (which doesn't work because of the mising data)
2. Converting to string and converting directly using `pd.Series.to_datetime` but this fails because of the decimal point
3. Using `pd.Series.to_datetime` and `format=%H%M.0` but this fails because of the NAs
4. Converting to string and calling `.str.rstrip('.0')` and `pd.Series.to_datetime` with `format=%H%M.0` but this fails because strings like '3'
5. Converting to string, calling `.str.rstrip('.0').str.zfill(4)` and then using `pd.Series.to_datetime` with `format=%H%M` afterwards but I get an error `unconverted data remains: 5`
6. Replacing NAs with `-1` and converting to int, reconverting to string and using `pd.Series.to_datetime` with `format=%H%M` and I get the same message as 4)

Is there a way to do it in pandas?

Comment: The `NaN`s will never convert - or do you want a default value for them? Your approach 5. will give you results when you use `pd.to_datetime()` with `errors="coerce"` (`.to_datetime()` is not an attribute of a `pd.Series`). Afterwards do `.dt.time` to get the time part.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import strptime
test = pd.DataFrame([703.0, 0.0, pd.NA], columns=["time"])
series = "0" + test["time"].fillna(0.0).astype(int).astype(str)
for i in series:
    print(strptime(i, "%H%M"))
```

I'm filling NA with 0.0 which will be 12am default time, but I don't know what you would like for default time.
Parsing to int to lose the last .0, to string and prepend a 0, which would be missing if it is 12am.
Interestingly, the pd.Series.to_datetime won't work with the exact same format string for me, but maybe this also solves your problem by not using pandas for the loop.
Maybe there is a better with pandas, but I hope this one helps